# SSIS add a new row for CASE statement

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis

We are extracting data from azure and loading it into a flat file using SSIS.

There was a new requirement added to this package where i need to create a new record with the same information except for one field where if it has a value "Z" it must create a new record with "A" for this particular field.

I don't want to insert it in the source table but want to insert while it loads in the flat file.

I  have given an example below , please have a look at it.

```
Regular output flat file:

 Name    Age    Type

 Ravi   21       Z

Requested output flat file:

 Name     Age    Type

 Ravi     21      Z

 Ravi     21      A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this with a script transformation.

Another way is to split your dataflow with a multicast, and on one side, get rid of all the rows except Type "Z", and replace the "Z" with an "A", and then UNION ALL the two sides back together.